# Are there any 3D modeling libraries written in java

Tags: java, bspline

I've found OpenNurbs, but it's written in C++, I need a 3D modeling library in java.

What I really need is a B-Spline class which can be constructed with some interpolation points.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL can render NURBS, java has a wrapper here: http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/

Some info on working with NURBS in OpenGL:

http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall09/cps124/notes/12_curves/opengl_nurbs.pdf

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bezier_patches__fullscreen_fix/18003/